# Python:get a couple of values from two different list

Tags: python, list, random

Does the Python has a built-in method I can get a couple of values from two differnet list in a random way?

ex:

```
listOne = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']
listTwo = [1, 2, 3]

# I want to get the result:
# ('Blue',3),('Red',2),('Green',1)
# or ('Blue',2),('Red',3),('Green',1)
# or ('Blue',1),('Red',2),('Green',3)
# and so on...how can I use a method get this result in a random way?
```

Comment: -1 for putting no thought or research into this

Comment: Why do people think there should be a builtin for _everything_? The beauty is having a small number of builtins that can be composed together to solve problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a random pairing, you could use `random.shuffle()`:

```
>>> import random
>>> listOne = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']
>>> listTwo = [1, 2, 3]
>>> random.shuffle(listTwo)
>>> zip(listOne, listTwo)
[('Blue', 3), ('Red', 2), ('Green', 1)]
>>> random.shuffle(listTwo)
>>> zip(listOne, listTwo)
[('Blue', 2), ('Red', 1), ('Green', 3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `random.choice` to do this:

```
listOne = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']
listTwo = [1, 2, 3]

import random
print (random.choice(listOne), random.choice(listTwo))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> listOne = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']
>>> listTwo = [1, 2, 3]
>>> map(choice, (listOne, listTwo))
['Green', 1]
```

Comment: That's a bit more concise than my answer :)